# How to get list of urls from a URL recursively with filtering

Tags: command-line, wget

I want to get list of URLs that contains `vimeo.com` from a web site recursively by a command , so that I can pipe it to [vimeo_downloader.sh](https://github.com/johnteslade/vimeo-downloader).

I prefer to use `wget`, but also I'm happy with other options.

#### Example

`index.html`

```
<a href="01.html">01</a>
<a href="02.html">02</a>
<a href="03.html">03</a>
<a href="04.html">04</a>
<a href="05.html">05</a>
<a href="06.html">06</a>
```

`01.html`

```
...
... src="//player.vimeo.com/video/xxxxxxxxxx?api=1" ...
...
```

Likewise `02.html` to `06.html` have a vimeo's URL.
How to get all vimeo URLs from `01~06.html`?

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Like this site http://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_html_v2 . It's Japanese site though. I want to download 16 lessons vimeo videos file in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the list of URL's then parse out the links to feed to the download. As you are using an external program to do the downloading rather than `wget` you don't really need `wget`s recursive download options.

Assuming GNU `grep` which allows you to print only the matching text you can grab the vimeo urls with:

```
wget -q -O - -i urllist.txt | grep -oi "http://vimeo.com/[0-9]\+"
```

Then to feed that into the downloader

```
urls=$(wget -q -O - -i urllist.txt | grep -oi "http://vimeo.com/[0-9]\+")
for url in $urls; do
  echo "Downloading [$url]"
  vimeo_downloader.sh "$url"
done
```